# How do I load the save-state dictionary of a transformer?

Tags: python, pickle, huggingface-transformers, torch

I downloaded the save-state dictionary of my fine-tuned transformers model to a .pkl file and I am now trying to load this into a Jupyter notebook as below:

```
# Load the saved state dictionary
model_state_dict = torch.load('BERT_state_dict.pkl', map_location=torch.device('cpu'))

# Load the tokenizer and create a new transformer model using the saved state dictionary
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased', state_dict=model_state_dict)
```

However, I receive an error:

```
RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but torch.cuda.is_available() is False. If you are running on a CPU-only machine, please use torch.load with map_location=torch.device('cpu') to map your storages to the CPU.
```

I am aware the model was training on a GPU, but I made the necessary change in my code and I still get this error?

Any tips appreciated, thanks.